# Why is the Qt event loop left

Tags: qt, event-loop, qmessagebox

I want a small program doing the following:

1. start a single-shot QTimer
2. when it times out, a QMessageBox is shown
3. if button "Continue" is clicked, the box is closed and the timer restarted
4. if button "Stop" is clicked, the box is closed and the application exited

The problem I have is that the event loop is left as soon as I hide the message box. The box is displayed only once. I reproduced my program in a console version and it runs as expected. Here is my code. Thanks in advance for your help.

**main.c**

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "TimedDialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  TimedDialog dialog(&app, SLOT(quit()));
  dialog.run();

  return app.exec();
}
```

**TimedDialog.h**

```
#ifndef TIMED_DIALOG_H
#define TIMED_DIALOG_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

class QMessageBox;
class QPushButton;
class QAbstractButton;

class TimedDialog : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  TimedDialog(
    QObject const * receiver,
    char const * method);

  ~TimedDialog();

  void run(void);

signals:
  void stop(void);

private:
  QMessageBox* _box;
  QPushButton* _buttonContinue;
  QPushButton* _buttonStop;
  QTimer _timer;

  static int const DELAY = 2 * 1000; // [ms]

private slots:
  void onTimeout(void);
  void onButtonClicked(QAbstractButton * button);
};

#endif
```

**TimedDialog.cpp**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPushButton>

#include "TimedDialog.h"

TimedDialog::TimedDialog(
  QObject const * receiver,
  char const * method)
  : QObject(),
  _box(0),
  _buttonContinue(0),
  _buttonStop(0),
  _timer()
{
  _box = new QMessageBox();
  _box->setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
  _box->setText("Here is my message!");

  _buttonContinue = new QPushButton("Continue");
  _box->addButton(_buttonContinue, QMessageBox::AcceptRole);

  _buttonStop = new QPushButton("Stop");
  _box->addButton(_buttonStop, QMessageBox::RejectRole);

  _timer.setSingleShot(true);

  assert(connect(&_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout())));
  assert(connect(_box, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton *)), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked(QAbstractButton *))));
  assert(connect(this, SIGNAL(stop()), receiver, method));
}

TimedDialog::~TimedDialog()
{
  delete _box;
}

void TimedDialog::onTimeout(void)
{
  _box->show();
}

void TimedDialog::onButtonClicked(QAbstractButton * button)
{
  _box->hide();

  if (button == _buttonContinue)
  {
    _timer.start(DELAY);
  }
  else
  {
    emit stop();
  }
}

void TimedDialog::run(void)
{
  _timer.start(DELAY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The created timer is being set as `singleshot`, which has already called `timeout`.

If you look at [QTimer source code](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qtimer.cpp?h=5.4) for the call to `start()` you can see it states: -

> If singleShot is true, the timer will be activated only once.

You could fix and simplify the code with the class function [QTimer::singleShot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that the problem is not with the single-shot timer because I can run a console program based on the same timer principle. Once the "Continue" button is pressed, the timer is restarted and I expect that the program keeps on running. What it doesn't do.